# Find and replace string with dot in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find and replace a part of string if present in string.

String is like `'1.png,2.png,3.jpg,4.gif'`

I want find `1.png` in this string and then replace it if exist with `1.jpg`.

I am not able to find it using `search()` and `indexOf()` method.

and since i am not able to find it i cannot replace it.

I am trying this way

```
var str = '1.png'
var new_str = '1.jpg'
var main_str = '1.png,2.png,3.jpg,4.gif';

if(main_str.indexOf(str) > 0){
alert('found')
// now replace it with new_str
}
else{
alert('not found')
}
```

I have tried following combination but these are not working.

```
main_str.indexOf('str') > 0
main_str.indexOf(/\str/) > 0
main_str.indexOf(/\"str"/) > 0
main_str.indexOf(str) > 0
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of `1.png` in your string is actually 0, that is why your condition fails. Correct way is to check whether index is not negative, since `indexOf` returns -1 if substring is not found:

```
if(main_str.indexOf(str) >= 0){
```

but even better approach here is to use `replace`:

```
main_str.replace(str, new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the replacement using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
main_str = main_str.replace(str, new_str)
```

If you want to replace more than one occurrence, use

```
main_str = main_str.replace(new RegExp(str,'g'), new_str)
```

If you want to alert before replacing, do this :

```
var r = new RegExp(str,'g');
if (main_str.match(r)) {
   alert('found')
   main_str = main_str.replace(r, new_str)
} else {
   alert('not found')
}
```

Comment: I need to confirm before replacing.

Comment: @TallboY: what do you want to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `main_str` contains `1.png` at index 0, you can never find it with the check `main_str.indexOf('str') > 0`. Remeber that javascript returns -1 if not found and not zero. So you'll have to update your condition to:

```
main_str.indexOf('str') != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var str="1.png,2.png,3.jpg,4.gif";
var newStr=str.replace(".png",".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the replace method:

```
var str = '1.png,2.png,3.jpg,4.gif';
var result=str.replace('1.png','1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var str = "1.png,2.png,3.jpg,4.gif";
var re = /(.png)/i;
var found = str.match(re);

//now ask the user or do whatever else is needed
if (found){
  found = confirm("Really overwrite");
}

if (found){
  str = str.replace(re, ".jpg");
}
```

I allow in the string now also upper case or mixed case, like `".Png"` or `".PNG"`